# using event after catalog collection load doesn't get the count right

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I'm trying to modify items in a collection on page load (catalog) and using the event: `catalog_product_collection_load_after`

and the code for the event is :

```
$observer->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => array_keys($_excludeProducts)))
            ->clear()
            ->load();
```

this does exclude product(s) but the count is wrong. like there're 5 products in the collection and on the grid as well but the count is 6 items.
How can i correct this?

Comment: the load event is not fired for `getSize()` and I'm not too sure about `count()` so it makes sense. A solution I don't have for you at this moment

Comment: Wait, you load the collection again in `load_after`? Even if Magento is smart enough to not go into endless recursion, why don't you use `load_before` to add the field to filter?

Comment: @fschmengler it goes into recursion when using `load_before`

Comment: Only if you call `load()` in the observer, which you should not and need not then

Comment: (these're just desperate attempts) removing `load()` and using `load_before` in event didn't help either.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are the counts right if you remove what you have in your observer?

Comment: the count is right without the filtering collection. but its not updated based on the filter

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can use count() function,But not sure 100%.

Basically `count()` is give result after ***load()***  executed that reason it will give you proper result

```
 public function count()
    {
        $this->load();
        return count($this->_items);
    }
```

### See at Varien_Data_Collection class.

***count()*** may be give you ***proper result whenever you remove clear()***  from collection.As this make ***collection load false***.`setIsLoaded(false)` and ***remove all element from Collection***

See at function:

> ```
>  public function clear()
>     {
>         $this->_setIsLoaded(false);
>         $this->_items = array();
>         return $this;
>     }
> ```